# undefined method `rels` for #<Neo4j::Core::Node:xxxxxxxx>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Recently I upgraded to Neo4j 3.1.3, Neo4j.rb 8.0.13, and Neo4j-core 7.1.2. Since then, rels method throws `undefined method 'rels' for #<Neo4j::Core::Node:xxxxxxxx>` error.

My query is,
`student.rels(dir: :outgoing, type: :enrolled_in).count`

Along with `rels` method, `create_rel` method is not working as well. I've been reading the docs to see if these two methods have been deprecated from newer versions, but no luck so far.

Comment: Haven't checked, but try out `relationships` instead, other parts of Neo4j have also made that move, maybe this has too.

Comment: now the error has changed to: `undefined method 'relationships' for #<Student:xxxxxxxxxxx>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read the [upgrade guide](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/UpgradeGuide.html) before reading the rest of this answer.

The `rels` relationship was not added to the `Neo4j::Core::Node` objects which replaced the old `Node` objects in the old API.  I believe we also had a `rels` method in `ActiveNode`.

If you are using `ActiveNode`, the replacement is to define an association.  Something like:

```
class Student
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  has_many :out, :all_nodes, type: :enrolled_in, model_class: false
end

# Then you can do:
student.all_nodes.count
```

However the fact that you're only following the `enrolled_in` relationship makes me think that this might be going to specific nodes (maybe `Course`?).  If so I'd suggest doing:

```
class Course
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
end

class
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  has_many :out, :courses, type: :enrolled_in 
  # model_class of `Course` will be assumed based on the association's name
end
```

If you aren't using `ActiveNode` but rather the `neo4j-core` gem directly, you should use a Cypher query